# Maven Plugin Error in Eclipse oxygen

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

Can anyone help me with this?

Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
**org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6** or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for **org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6**

I  tried the following ways:

1. Right click on project. Go to 'Maven' and click on update project. Click on OK.
2. Close the project in Eclipse. Delete the project in Eclipse ( but not the contents ). Navigate to the project in file system and delete .classpath and .project files. Go back to Eclipse and import the project as "existing maven project".

Please suggest.

Comment: Try installing the M2E plugin from help&gt;Install new Software in eclipse If you haven't and build again. That might work. I had a similar problem.
Also, is there any build error when you create a new maven project?

Comment: Please copy an paste your error, do not post it as an image

Comment: @AyushKumar - I was able to create a Maven Project successfully. The changes that I made was in the Remote Catalog. I added (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml, maven Catalog) to the archetypes but we have Nexus Repository
Preference: Maven>Archetypes> Add Remote Catalog: Catalog File: http://www.nexus.*****.com/repository/maven-central/, Description: maven Central.

Comment: @AyushKumar, Yes I've 12 build errors in pom.xml file
1.**CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.5.1:**

2. **Failed to read artifact descriptor for info.cukes:cucumber-java:jar:1.2.4**

3. **Failed to read artifact descriptor for info.cukes:cucumber-junit:jar:1.2.4**

4. **Missing artifact info.cukes:cucumber-java:jar:1.2.4**

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what it helped me when I was facing

1. You can right-click on your project
2. Select Maven > Update Project
3. Select "Force Update of snapshots and release"